# Can't edit products after upgrade from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I've just upgraded to 2.3.3 from 2.3.2 however if I now try and edit a product it gives me this error in the browser:

```
An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
```

If I look in exception.log I can see these two lines:

```
[2019-11-03 18:29:18] temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required. Enter and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException(code: 0): \"accountId\" is required. Enter and try again. at vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:91)"} []
[2019-11-03 18:29:18] main.CRITICAL: Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded at vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:26)"} []
```

I've tried doing the usual flush cache, remove generated etc. I've also tried disabling modules but still can't find a solution.

I'm assuming that it's the unable to serialize value error but given it does it on every product and doesn't give any more info about the error I'm a bit stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix in file: file/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

Add into this code:

```
public function serialize($data)
{
    $result = json_encode($data);
    if (false === $result) {
        if(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_UTF8){
            $data = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($data);
            $result = json_encode($data);
            if($result){
                return $result;
            }
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to serialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
    }
    return $result;
}
public static function convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($dat)
{
    if (is_string($dat)) {
        return utf8_encode($dat);
    } elseif (is_array($dat)) {
        $ret = [];
        foreach ($dat as $i => $d) $ret[ $i ] = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($d);

        return $ret;
    } elseif (is_object($dat)) {
        foreach ($dat as $i => $d) $dat->$i = self::convert_from_latin1_to_utf8_recursively($d);

        return $dat;
    } else {
        return $dat;
    }
}
```

Reply me when you have the result.

Comment: Thank you, it now gives me this: https://onetimesecret.com/secret/b39c5ukj6t1luuuzdq64mdtievqnk3k

Comment: We can see anything in the site you sent? Could you screen shot the result for us?